# How can I automatically add author and copyright info to newly created ipython notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'd like to pre-pend a simple author and copyright clause the beginning of newly created ipython notebooks.  Is this possible? If so how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

We want to support this in metadata at notebook top level, but nobody has taken time to write a proposal for metadata structure, how to edit it, and how to show it.

This would be usefull for view on nbviewer, but also for conversion to LaTeX, and other format. It might just be slightly more complicated that at first thought, as you probably want the Authors to be more that just first name/last name (like a full embeded vcard for example).

If you want to work on that you are welcomed, otherwise in the meantime I suggest adding a simple markdown cell at top with those info.

This should be easy to do on a buch on notebook at once as they are easy parsable json.

Comment: It's been a couple years. Is this answer still correct?